# PHP: Array not working, key not exists, but it exists

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have an array (a line of an csv file). This array contains the following data (`var_dump($rowData)`).

```
array(8) {
  ["Kategorie"]=>
  string(12) "Bio- Bäcker"
  ["Name"]=>
  string(31) "A nice name"
  ["Adresse"]=>
  string(27) "the street 13"
  ["PLZ"]=>
  string(5) "08056"
  ["Ort"]=>
  string(7) "Zwickau"
  ["Tel"]=>
  string(14) "0375/390 xxx"
  ["Mail"]=>
  string(24) "info@doktor-xxx.xx"
  ["Website"]=>
  string(27) "http://doktor-xxx.xx/"
}
```

By getting values by running `$rowData['key']` I get an error - but only by the first array key (Kategorie). PHP is telling me, the key doesn't exists.

I tried something around, all other keys are callable, but not the first.

```
$profileName = $rowData['Name'];
$profileAddress = $rowData['Adresse'];
$profileZip = $rowData['PLZ'];
$profileCity = $rowData['Ort'];
$profilePhone = $rowData['Tel'];
$profileWebsite = $rowData['Website'];
$profileMail = $rowData['Mail'];
$profileCategory = $rowData['Kategorie'];
```

Just don't know what's wrong with my code...

Comment: Try `$rowData->Kategorie` it might work that way instead

Comment: It is an array, not an object!

Comment: Can you post the line of code that produces the error? Something is missing here.

Comment: Maybe you have some hidden character in the key. Try `var_dump(array_keys($rowData))` to see if the key length matches what you expect

Comment: @Aleeeeee `var_dump($rowData)` is allways showing all of the characters of the keys.

Comment: What's the error that you get? Is it the warning about the key not existing? I'm just making sure it's not an error about charsets or anything. Also, if you call `array_key_exists("Kategorie", $rowData)`, does it show as existing?

Comment: Might be an encoding issue, a character that looks like the character you expect it to be. Have a try using copy and paste to check the key.

Comment: In general: could you please post what _exactly_ a `var_dump($rowData);` outputs? Thanks.

Comment: @RobbieToyota the result is false.

Comment: @AntonDachauer let's go low level: `echo bin2hex(array_keys($rowData)[0])`. So we get the hex representation of the actual key

Comment: @arkascha I checked this, thats also false,

Comment: @AntonDachauer but you didn't show us the output of `var_dump(array_keys($rowData))` (please note **array_keys**)

Comment: @Aleeeeee `array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "Kategorie"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Name"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Adresse"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "PLZ"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "Ort"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "Tel"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "Mail"
  [7]=>
  string(7) "Website"
}
`

Comment: `Kategorie` is definitely not 12 characters; looks like a charset discrepancy to me

Comment: @MarkBaker The 12 refers to the value `Bio- Bäcker`, not the key. The var_dump should output 12 for that value

Comment: A combination of UTF characters with missing multi byte extension in the code.

Comment: @yanman1234 No, that refers to "Kategorie", it is a dump of `array_keys(.....)` (I assume).

Comment: @MarkBaker `var_dump` doesn't tell you that the key is 12 characters, it means the value of the key.

Comment: @arkascha The question clearly shows `var_dump($array)`, which is the array, not the keys.

Comment: This is fishy... if I copy & paste that key it has only 9 characters. Could this question be a joke?

Comment: @yanman1234 The question does, but not the comment a bit further up.

Comment: And this is why that comment should be an edit... Yeah that length should be 9, not 12. Something else is going on

Comment: @Anton - `array(8) { [0]=> string(12) "Kategorie"` (assuming that is your `var_dump` of `array_keys()`) is telling you that `Kategorie` is a string of 12 bytes length

Comment: I just converted the csv file again to utf-8 (the used character set). nothing has been changed.

Comment: @AntonDachauer How would you do _that_? Without knowing what encoding it actually is in?

Comment: Voting to close the question since it is _not_ a programming issue but most likely unclean usage of provided data.

Comment: @arkascha I'm using notepad++, that shows me the used character set.

Comment: @AntonDachauer Please note that you can never rely on such "features". It is _impossible_ to automatically detect the encoding of a text file in a reliable manner. That is a _guess_ at best. In general: you need to know what encoding the data is it. Everything else is guesswork.

Comment: @arkascha the csv file is an converted excel file. I just selected "UTF-8 CSV" to create an csv file - is that wrong?

Comment: I cannot say. And frankly I think that is nothing we should discuss here. It is obvious that the key you post is not the key you are working with (I checked), so this is a data issue, _not_ a programming issue.

Comment: @AntonDachauer You likely have some invisible characters in the stored value that happened due to the conversion. There are many php built-in functions that can handle this.

Comment: use: print_r(array_keys($array)); for seeing all the array keys it has!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are hidden characters in the key name - by running this code, it works:

```
foreach ($rowData as $key => $value) {
    $newKey = str_replace('?', '', utf8_decode($key));
    $rowData[$newKey] = $value;
}
```

Maybe not the best solution, but it works (in this case).